# Decode an base64 encoded string through php in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, base64

## The question

How can I decode a string with JavaScript that's encoded in php and maintain the "åäö" letters?

### Overview of the problem

As the title states I'm trying to decode a base64 encoded string that I generate from my php code. It all works fine except for the letters "åäö" that the Swedish alphabet ends with.

#### Output exemple:

```
 å ä ö Å Ä Ö   =>   Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã Ã Ã
```

### Code

#### The base64 JavaScript I'm using

```javascript
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Nick Galbreath
 * http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/#svn/trunk/javascript
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

/* base64 encode/decode compatible with window.btoa/atob
 *
 * window.atob/btoa is a Firefox extension to convert binary data (the "b")
 * to base64 (ascii, the "a").
 *
 * It is also found in Safari and Chrome.  It is not available in IE.
 *
 * if (!window.btoa) window.btoa = base64.encode
 * if (!window.atob) window.atob = base64.decode
 *
 * The original spec's for atob/btoa are a bit lacking
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa
 *
 * window.btoa and base64.encode takes a string where charCodeAt is [0,255]
 * If any character is not [0,255], then an exception is thrown.
 *
 * window.atob and base64.decode take a base64-encoded string
 * If the input length is not a multiple of 4, or contains invalid characters
 *   then an exception is thrown.
 */
base64 = {};
base64.PADCHAR = '=';
base64.ALPHA = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
base64.getbyte64 = function(s,i) {
    // This is oddly fast, except on Chrome/V8.
    //  Minimal or no improvement in performance by using a
    //   object with properties mapping chars to value (eg. 'A': 0)
    var idx = base64.ALPHA.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
    if (idx == -1) {
    throw "Cannot decode base64";
    }
    return idx;
}

base64.decode = function(s) {
    // convert to string
    s = "" + s;
    var getbyte64 = base64.getbyte64;
    var pads, i, b10;
    var imax = s.length
    if (imax == 0) {
        return s;
    }

    if (imax % 4 != 0) {
    throw "Cannot decode base64";
    }

    pads = 0
    if (s.charAt(imax -1) == base64.PADCHAR) {
        pads = 1;
        if (s.charAt(imax -2) == base64.PADCHAR) {
            pads = 2;
        }
        // either way, we want to ignore this last block
        imax -= 4;
    }

    var x = [];
    for (i = 0; i < imax; i += 4) {
        b10 = (getbyte64(s,i) << 18) | (getbyte64(s,i+1) << 12) |
            (getbyte64(s,i+2) << 6) | getbyte64(s,i+3);
        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10 >> 16, (b10 >> 8) & 0xff, b10 & 0xff));
    }

    switch (pads) {
    case 1:
        b10 = (getbyte64(s,i) << 18) | (getbyte64(s,i+1) << 12) | (getbyte64(s,i+2) << 6)
        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10 >> 16, (b10 >> 8) & 0xff));
        break;
    case 2:
        b10 = (getbyte64(s,i) << 18) | (getbyte64(s,i+1) << 12);
        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10 >> 16));
        break;
    }
    return x.join('');
}

base64.getbyte = function(s,i) {
    var x = s.charCodeAt(i);
    if (x > 255) {
        throw "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5";
    }
    return x;
}


base64.encode = function(s) {
    if (arguments.length != 1) {
    throw "SyntaxError: Not enough arguments";
    }
    var padchar = base64.PADCHAR;
    var alpha   = base64.ALPHA;
    var getbyte = base64.getbyte;

    var i, b10;
    var x = [];

    // convert to string
    s = "" + s;

    var imax = s.length - s.length % 3;

    if (s.length == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < imax; i += 3) {
        b10 = (getbyte(s,i) << 16) | (getbyte(s,i+1) << 8) | getbyte(s,i+2);
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 >> 18));
        x.push(alpha.charAt((b10 >> 12) & 0x3F));
        x.push(alpha.charAt((b10 >> 6) & 0x3f));
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 & 0x3f));
    }
    switch (s.length - imax) {
    case 1:
        b10 = getbyte(s,i) << 16;
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 >> 18) + alpha.charAt((b10 >> 12) & 0x3F) +
               padchar + padchar);
        break;
    case 2:
        b10 = (getbyte(s,i) << 16) | (getbyte(s,i+1) << 8);
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 >> 18) + alpha.charAt((b10 >> 12) & 0x3F) +
               alpha.charAt((b10 >> 6) & 0x3f) + padchar);
        break;
    }
    return x.join('');
}
```

#### The implementation

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(
        base64.decode( '<?php echo base64_encode( "å ä ö Å Ä Ö" ); ?>' ) );
</script>
```

### Edit

The script I found that worked:
*(someone asked me for this, so here it is)*

```javascript
var Base64 =
{
    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input)
    {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input)
    {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string)
    {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext)
    {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a character encoding problem, make sure all you files are using the same encoding (UTF-8?) even you JavaScript files.

If not try searching to see if others have experienced the same problem, most likely with those special characters. (I'm from Norway, so I know how it is with those damn characters ;)

If this don't solve your problem, try another JavaScript base64 decoder.

Comment: Thanks, my first guest to. I have checked the encoding and it's all UTF-8 though.

Comment: That's good :) Encoding format is always the most obvious cause of errors like this, but sometimes it's just the code ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might give this a shot to see if it solves your problem:

http://phpjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for your input. Never heard of this before, will look in to it.

Comment: @ErikLandvall : Yeah, I just found it and got all excited. XD